# Dynamically add radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a simple javascript quiz application ,with `radio` buttons.I've almost finished making the application,but what if I want to add a question to allQuestions array, which has options not equal to 3(for example 2 or 4).
For example, what can I do to remove or add `radio` buttons depending on the number of options a question has,for instance, question 1 has only 2 options ,but 3 `radio` buttons & question 2 has 4 options but three `radio` buttons.
Code:

```js
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of India?",
    choices: ["Rahul Gandhi", "Arvind Kejrival", "Narendra Damodardas Modi","Dr.Manmohan Singh"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump", "Barack Obama", "Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },

  {
    question: " Who averaged one patent for every three weeks of his life?",
    choices: ["Thomas Edison", "Tesla", "Einstein"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "What continent is cut into two fairly equal halves by the Tropic of Capricorn?",
    choices: ["Africa", "South America", "Australia"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "What explorer introduced pigs to North America?",
    choices: ["Christopher Columbus", "Galileo", "Mussorie"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "What F-word is defined in physics as a “nuclear reaction in which nuclei combine to form more massive nuclei”? ",
    choices: ["Furnace", "Fusion", "Fission"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },

  {
    question: "What was the first planet to be discovered using the telescope, in 1781?",
    choices: ["Uranus", "Jupiter", "Mars"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the chief minister of West Bengal, India?",
    choices: ["Buddhadev Bhattacharya", "Jyoti Basu", "Mamta Banerjee"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "Which is the fastest growing religion in the world?",
    choices: ["Islam", "Christianity", "Hinduism"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }
  /*
   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   } */
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentquestion = 0;
  var correctAnswers = 0;
  $("#container").hide();
  $('#start').click(function() {
    $("#container").fadeIn();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
      max: allQuestions.length - 1,
      value: 0
    });
  });

  $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
  $('label[for=option0]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[0] + "<br/>");
  $('label[for=option1]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[1] + "<br/>");
  $('label[for=option2]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[2] + "<br/>");

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name=option]:checked").val() == allQuestions[currentquestion].correctAnswer) {
      correctAnswers++;
    };
    currentquestion++;
    $(function() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: currentquestion
      });
    });
    if (currentquestion < allQuestions.length) {
      $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
      $('label[for=option0]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[0] + "<br/>");
      $('label[for=option1]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[1] + "<br/>");
      $('label[for=option2]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[2] + "<br/>");
      if (currentquestion == allQuestions.length - 1) {
        $('#next').html("Submit");
        //$('#next').off("click");
        $('#next').click(function() {
          $("#container").hide();
          $("#result").html("Your Score is " + correctAnswers + " out of " + currentquestion + " and your percentage is " + (correctAnswers * 100 / (currentquestion)) + "%").hide();
          $("#result").fadeIn(1500);
        });

      }

    };
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #79BD9A;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.ui-widget-header {
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: #FF7860 !important; //Any colour can go here
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  /*text-align: center;*/
}
h3,
#next {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
input[name="option"] {
  float: left;
}
#form div {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 205px;
}
#progressbar {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  margin: 5em;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<a href="#" id="start" class="button">Let's Begin</a>
<br/>
<div id="container">
  <h3 id="question"></h3>
  <form id="form">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked>
      <label for='option0'></label>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="option1">
      <label for='option1'></label>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="option2">
      <label for='option2'></label>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </form>

  <br/>
  <a href="#" id="next" class="button">Next</a>
  <br/>
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLwjzx8o/14/)

Comment: @JacobGray, my bad..but these are supposed to be dummy questions anyway..I'll be changing all the questions once I'm done with the code..

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question, specifically about the problem?

Comment: @JacobGray I've edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way: I also edited the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kingychiu/vLwjzx8o/16/

```
    function setupOptions(){
      $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
      var options = allQuestions[currentquestion].choices;
      var formHtml ='';
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        formHtml += '<div><input type="radio" name="option" value="'+i+'" id="option'+i+'"><label for="option'+i+'">'+allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[i]+'<br/></label><br/></div>';
      }
      $('#form').html(formHtml);
}
```

Btw, to do dynamic data binding with ui, I suggest you use Angular js, the ng-repeat, which make the code look better.

Comment: @nign that worked thanks..I know the code is pretty ugly and moreover duplicated,but I'm learning..I'm an absolute beginner.This is my first piece of code ,which itself took three days to complete..Yet to learn Angular,js..

Comment: @Rashid I am not saying your code is ugly, your initial code in jsfiddle is great.lol. I just dont like putting HTML code in JS string (hard to debug, find missing tags etc).
With other libraries like angular, we can avoid that kind of "HTML string".

Comment: better does not imply the original one is bad, right? :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a for each loop:

```
$(allQuestions).each(function( index ) {
  // Loop your entirely div + input + label and use the index to determine the question
  /*
   <div>
       <input type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked>
       <label for='option0'></label>
       <br/>
   </div>
  */
  // Increment current question or use index
});
```